# Find next element of same type through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, find

Hello guys please check the html below.

```
    <div class="mainDiv2">
        <a href="home00.html" >home00</a>
        <a href="home0.html" >home0</a><br /><br />
        <h1>Employee List</h1>
        <a href="home.html" >home</a><br /><br />
        <a href="home2.html" >home2</a>
        <a href="home3.html" >home3</a>
        <h1>Employee List2</h1>
        <a href="home4.html">home4</a>
        <a href="home5.html">home5</a>
        <h1>Employee List3</h1>
        <a href="home6.html">home6</a>
        <a href="home7.html">home7</a>
        <a href="home8.html">home8</a>
        <a href="home9.html" class="active">home9</a>

        <p>
            {!PageTitle}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="prevRec" href="#">Pre</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="nextRec" href="#">Next</a>
    </div>
```

what i want is that. If there is a class `.active` implemented on an href then i want to get the previous and next element href value of same type. In current html it will return

Pre : home8.html
Next : Empty

and in following case

```
    <div class="mainDiv2">
        <a href="home00.html" >home00</a>
        <a href="home0.html" >home0</a><br /><br />
        <h1>Employee List</h1>
        <a href="home.html" >home</a><br /><br />
        <a href="home2.html" >home2</a>
        <a href="home3.html" >home3</a>
        <h1>Employee List2</h1>
        <a href="home4.html">home4</a>
        <a href="home5.html">home5</a>
        <h1>Employee List3</h1>
        <a href="home6.html" class="active">home6</a>
        <a href="home7.html">home7</a>
        <a href="home8.html">home8</a>
        <a href="home9.html" >home9</a>

        <p>
            {!PageTitle}
        </p>
    </div>
```

it will return

Pre : home5.html
Next : home7.html

Note : Please remember that there is h1 tag between the a tags.. Just to let you know guys i have already the answer of this question.. but i want different solution. I don't think that this is the proper solution.

In case this is my answer :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var currActive = $('div[class="mainDiv2"]').find('a.active');

        if ($(currActive).nextAll('a').length > 0) {
            var nextHref = $(currActive).nextAll('a').attr("href")
            $("#nextRec").attr("href", nextHref);
        }
        else
            $("#nextRec").attr("href", 'http://www.google.com').text("Home");

        //--------------

        if ($(currActive).prevAll('a').length > 0) {
            var preHref = $(currActive).prevAll('a').attr("href")
            $("#prevRec").attr("href", preHref);
        }
        else
            $("#prevRec").attr("href", 'http://www.google.com').text("Home");
    });
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `prevAll()` and `nextAll()` to get the required elements, even when there is an `h1` between them. Try this:

```js
var $active = $('a.active');
var prev = $active.prevAll('a').first().attr('href');
var next = $active.nextAll('a').first().attr('href');

console.log(prev);
console.log(next);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv2">
  <a href="home00.html">home00</a>
  <a href="home0.html">home0</a><br /><br />
  <h1>Employee List</h1>
  <a href="home.html">home</a><br /><br />
  <a href="home2.html">home2</a>
  <a href="home3.html">home3</a>
  <h1>Employee List2</h1>
  <a href="home4.html">home4</a>
  <a href="home5.html">home5</a>
  <h1>Employee List3</h1>
  <a href="home6.html" class="active">home6</a>
  <a href="home7.html">home7</a>
  <a href="home8.html">home8</a>
  <a href="home9.html">home9</a>
  <p>
    {!PageTitle}
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with prev/next by eliminating any element that is not a link, this will catch multiple active classes if exist:

```js
$('.mainDiv2').clone().find('*').remove('*:not("a")').end().find('.active').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next('a').attr('href');
  var prev = $(this).prev('a').attr('href');
  console.log(prev== undefined?'google.com':prev,next == undefined?'google.com':next);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv2">
  <a href="home00.html">home00</a>
  <a href="home0.html">home0</a><br /><br />
  <h1>Employee List</h1>
  <a href="home.html">home</a><br /><br />
  <a href="home2.html">home2</a>
  <a href="home3.html">home3</a>
  <h1>Employee List2</h1>
  <a href="home4.html">home4</a>
  <a href="home5.html">home5</a>
  <h1>Employee List3</h1>
  <a href="home6.html" class="active">home6</a>
  <a href="home7.html">home7</a>
  <a href="home8.html">home8</a>
  <a href="home9.html">home9</a>
  <a href="home10.html" class="active">home6</a>

  <p>
    {!PageTitle}
  </p>
</div>
```